# Сделать фото- зашифровать фото

Tags: android

Подскажите в какую сторону смотреть -приложение должно делать фото и шифровать его. Что лучше использовать? Самое простое что я придумал - пароль на рар архив.
Android 12-14.

Comment: Почитайте про Cipher. Вот здесь есть примеры https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-images-in-android/ .
Или вот похожий вопрос на StackOverflow
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28343431/android-simple-way-to-encrypt-an-image

Comment: Зашифровать в каком смысле? Что бы его нельзя было просмотреть?

Comment: А не приложение для поиска сокровищ ли вы там делаете?))

Comment: Такое уже есть...почитаю,Спс